# How to check for node's existence and nodes with specific attributes existence?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, vb.net

I'm looking for a way to determine if an specific node with an attribute exists, and get it's value.

Also, I need to know how to check if an specific node inside the node with the attribute exists:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Settings Name="Settings">
  <Category Name="CatTest1">
    <Printer1>Kitchen</Printer1>
  </Category>
  <Category Name="CatTest2">
    <Printer1>Kitchen02</Printer1>
    <Printer2>PrintToPdf</Printer2>
  </Category>
</Settings>
```

In this example:

1. I need a way to know if The node with the Attribute "Name='CatTest2'" exists
2. I need a way to know if inside  the node with the Attribute "Name='CatTest2'" exists the node called "Printer1"

I have tried several ways, but I'm stucked

```
    Dim NodeToCheck2 As XmlNode = xEle2.SelectSingleNode("Category")

    Dim testAttribute As XmlAttribute = CType(NodeToCheck2.Attributes.GetNamedItem("Name"), XmlAttribute)

    If testAttribute IsNot Nothing Then
        MsgPopUp("Name exists")
    Else
        MsgPopUp("Name doesn't exists")
    End If
```

In this code I try to check for an attribute named "Name" inside categories but it doesn't work.

I would really appreciate any help. Thanks in advance

Comment: Select**Single**Node selects a single node. Do some more research on xpath if you want to continue with the System.Xml namespace. If you are comfortable with LINQ, I suggest you use the classes in System.Xml.Linq

Answer (score 0):

Give this a go:

```
    Dim document = <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Settings Name="Settings">
  <Category Name="CatTest1">
    <Printer1>Kitchen</Printer1>
  </Category>
  <Category Name="CatTest2">
    <Printer1>Kitchen02</Printer1>
    <Printer2>PrintToPdf</Printer2>
  </Category>
</Settings>

    Dim existsCatTest2 =
        document _
            .Descendants() _
            .Any(Function(x) x.Attribute("Name")?.Value = "CatTest2")
            
    Dim existsCatTest2Printer1 =
        document _
            .Descendants() _
            .Where(Function(x) x.Attribute("Name")?.Value = "CatTest2") _
            .Any(Function(x) x.Element("Printer1") IsNot Nothing)
```